# What is meant by basic figures of a graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

In a theorem, there was mentioned that

> Let
> $P_G(λ) = |λI − A| = λ^n + a_1λ^{n−1} + \ldots + a_n$
> be the characteristic polynomial of an arbitrary undirected multigraph $G$.
> Call an “elementary figure”
> a) the graph K2, or
> b) every graph Cq ($q ≥ 1$) (loops being included with $q = 1$),
> call a “basic figure” U every graph all of whose components are elementary figures;

In that theorem what is basic figure? I am not able to understand. Please someone clarify my doubt.

Comment: It seems your reference defines "basic figure" to mean a "graph all of whose components are elementary figures", and "elementary figure" to mean "the graph K2, or every graph Cq (q ≥ 1)".

Comment: I'm sure you did not intend to commit plagiarism. What is the source of your quotation?

Comment: @bof: From googling, it seems the source is Theorem 1.3 (p. 32) of D. M. Cvetković, M. Doob, and H. Sachs, Spectra of Graphs: Theory and Application (New York: Academic Press, 1980), although there are various preprints quoting the quoted text verbatim (usually with the above reference given).

Answer (score 2):

As gvmh has indicated in the comments, these “basic figures” are just graphs in which every connected component is an edge or a cycle.

These are often called “Sachs graphs” after Horst Sachs who showed that the characteristic polynomial of a graph $G$ can be expressed as a weighted sum over all subgraphs of $G$ that are Sachs graphs.

This expression is similar to to the expression of the determinant of a matrix as a weighted sum over all permutations.

This is not surprising because Sachs’s expression is precisely obtained by interpreting the non-zero terms of the permutation expansion of the determinant of the matrix $x I - A$ in graph theory terms.